# Wiki that allows editing (from within!) complete frontend HTML/CSS

Tags: linux, open-source, cms, html-editor, wiki

I’m looking for a wiki (or a wiki-like CMS) with some special (probably rare) features.

#### Wiki basics

- create new page by linking to non-existent page and editing it
- page history (diff)
- list of recent changes
- text-based editor (some wiki syntax, but no WYSIWYG; should allow full HTML)
- restrict edit permission to registered users only (and allow disabling registration)

The editing workflow must be hassle-free (like it’s the case with probably any usual wiki): visit the page, go to the edit form, save it. No backend menus, no required preview, no required fields, etc.

#### Special features

- All frontend code (HTML and CSS, possibly JavaScript) must be editable from within the wiki, just like other wiki pages (i.e., with the same editor; offering also page history etc.).

  - The actual content of a wiki page should be inserted at a given position (e.g., by adding a template tag).
- Wiki functionality ("Edit" and "History" links, global navigation for recent changes etc.) must be visible for registered users only.

  - Access to those pages (e.g., by guessing the URL) should also be impossible for visitors (show 404 or 403).
- The public HTML must only contain the defined/editable frontend markup and the wiki page content. So the editor needs to have 100% control over the outputted markup (from *within* the wiki).

#### Not *required*, but would be great

- Support more than one "field" (apart from the wiki page main content): add a textarea for each template tag added in the HTML template to every edit page.
- From within the wiki, allow specifying the HTTP status code (e.g., for sending a 410) to be used, per page. In case of 3xx, allow specifying the target URLs.
- Allow defining which HTML the wiki syntax creates, from within the wiki.

#### Formal requirements

- It must be **FLOSS**.
- It must run natively on a **GNU/Linux** server.

Comment: For instance, the HTML of the wikitext editor should be editable? It requires that the editor's server-side generated HTML itself is totally templated, which is quite rare indeed. I guess you are aware that tricky mistakes could prevent you from editing anything.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: Sorry, I don't understand. What do you mean with "the HTML of the wikitext editor should be editable?" Do you mean the actual editor, or the whole edit page? Anyway, it’s "only" required that the published page’s HTML can be edited (i.e., those pages that will be visible for unregistered visitors).

Comment: I thought you wanted EVERYTHING to be editable. In fact you just want all public-facing pages to be editable? Does the public have the ability to edit pages?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: Correct, only the HTML/CSS of pages visible to unregistered users (i.e., public pages) need to be editable. -- No, unregistered users shall not be able to edit anything. Only registered users shall be able to see that it’s a wiki, to edit content and to edit HTML/CSS. (And registration shall be disabled.) (In fact, it could also be a single-user wiki.)

Comment: Goto http://www.wikimatrix.org and use there choice wizard to help you make the decision.

Comment: You could always use Github for permissions and pull requests. There's a way that you can always have the newest code on your server…

Answer (score 2):

*disclaimer: I haven't actually tried this, but sounds promising to me.*

maybe you could use the Mediawiki with extension [CodeEditor](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CodeEditor) (perhaps with [Scribunto](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Extension:Scribunto)):

> The CodeEditor extension extends the WikiEditor advanced editing
>   toolbar with an embedded Ace editor widget, providing some handy
>   features **for user/site JS, CSS pages**, and when Extension:Scribunto is
>   also installed, for pages in Module namespace

Answer (score 1):

Increasingly, the answer to requests that start with, "I need software to make a web [thing-a-ma-bob]," is WordPress.

I suggest [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org) with [Wiki Pro](https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/wordpress-wiki/) by WPMU DEV and whatever other plugins you need to fit your other specific needs and functions.

Comment: Does Wiki Pro allow editing of the whole frontend code (HTML/CSS/JS) *within* the wiki/WordPress? I can’t find this feature after skimming over their page.

Comment: Strangely, I cannot find a page on WPMU DEV that says, "All our code is open source," but it is. The following page references it: http://www.wpmayor.com/wpmu-dev-review/ As for editing, WordPress natively allows editing of most files, and plugins can allow you to access any file and edit it. Of course, many of us use programs such as Notepad++ to edit sensitive files, but I've also used the editor within WP to make quick changes. WPMU DEV has excellent pre-sales support, too. I asked them a ton of technical questions about Wiki Pro that helped me decide I didn't need something that powerful.